# Emulator Running in Nested Virtualization

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, virtual-machine, appium

The emulator is running using nested virtualization. This is not recommended. It may not work at all. And typically the performance is not quite good.
VM machine(Window10)

Comment: Is there a question? It sounds like you're running a Windows 10 Virtual Machine, and from within it, running an emulator? This is the "nested" part of the message.

Comment: @Jeppe actually it is an error message which I am getting when trying to run the emulator in Window 10 Virtual Machine.

Comment: Yes, and the "error" is telling you that it might not work as expected. Every layer of virtualization adds overhead and requires peripherals mapped correctly. One way to get rid of the message, is to run the emulator natively next to the VM.

Comment: I need to get the Citrix Admin to run emulator "next to the VM"; how is this done and can the emulator be installed and debugged from the Android Studio that is in the VM?